# Derivation of Morris's Algorithm

Tags: probability

I am following the derivation of Morris's algorithm given here:

https://algorithms.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/scribe1.pdf/604615257/scribe1.pdf

On page 3

They calculate $E[2^{X_n}]$

and in the second line and third line of the derivation they show:

$\Sigma_i 2 Pr[X_{n-1}= i-1] + \Sigma_i 2^i Pr[X_{n-1}= i] - \Sigma_i Pr[X_{n-1}= i]$

$= E[2^{X_n-1}]+1$

The middle term of the second line gives the first term in the third line, but how to the remaining two terms in the second line sum to one?

Thanks

Baz

Comment: Morris's not Moris's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} Pr(X_{n-1}=i-1) = Pr(X_{n-1} \text{ something between -1 and} \infty ) = 1$. So first term evaluates to 2 and similarly last term evaluates to -1. which gives us what we want.